# Open the same directory twice

Tags: visual-studio-code

On command line, I could open a directory like:

```
    code .
```

Now, I want two of the identical diretory opened and displayed in another window.
(It's not spliting the editor)
Then, I tried again.

```
    code .
```

Nothing happened.
There's still one directory opened.
How to achieve such a task?

Comment: Its not the exactly answer but might help.. Use another editor, like atom, sublime or brackets. Than you you can manage on vs code and check code in the others. Hope i could help.

Comment: I can duplicate the workspace, but I cannot run the debugger in the new window

Comment: @JoelV98's answer is the best: click file > duplicate workspace

Answer (score 506, accepted):

You can do this with the following ways:

1- Manually open a new window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>) and go to:

File > Add folder to Workspace. Then just select the folder.

2- Open the command panel (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>), enter `dupl`, and select `Workspaces: Duplicate Workspace in New Window`

*Source:* https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

Comment: I suggest an edit to clarify it's not the "dupl" that does what's asked, it just finds the "Workspaces: Duplicate Workspace in New Window" command that actually accomplishes the task.

Comment: @dipnik I have added the clarification, thank you for noticing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The originally accepted answer WAS ok but that functionality was deprecated while ago.

Comment: Is it okay that you just edited your answer to include [Elkhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567325/706561)?

Comment: @DiegoRicardoValdiviaArreola , this was very helpful! Just wanted to add that dupl copies whatever your current selection is. So one would have to go all the way again to add a folder and without selecting anything else, execute dupl!

Comment: How to turn this off? It is always opening two windows.

Comment: but cant different branch . i use branch A on first window and the second window from duplicate also automatic change to branch A , how to lock the branch ? i would like to open 2 different branch at same time with different workspace

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo You are looking for `git worktree`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree. Add a worktree and create a `.code-workspace` file inside it. Then from the command line you can run `code .code-workspace` in both your main project and your worktree, and they will be in different branches.

Answer (score 240):

In the latest version, it is actually much simpler.
In a window of the project you want to duplicate, open the command panel (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Ubuntu), then type `dupl` (and select `Workspaces: Duplicate As Workspace in New Window`), this will duplicate your workspace in a new window. Now you can have 2 windows of the same project at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, this should probably be the selected answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: command name: `Workspaces: Duplicate Workspace in New Window`

Comment: Thanks For this answer. Quick question I want to work on a different git branch still on the same project but using a different window. I wouldn't want changes reflected on the second branch to apply to the first one. And I mean changes like when I switch branches on window 2 the branch selected on window 1 should still be selected. Does this answer help with that?

Comment: @maykhid your need is better suited by using git worktrees: https://opensource.com/article/21/4/git-worktree

Answer (score 42):

click
file > duplicate workspace

Comment: Best answer! Brilliant!

Answer (score 9):

Click `Add workspace folder...` and open the same folder. Works for me, other solution doesn't work, just jump focus to another window.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the accepted answer is not correct as C14L indicates.

It can be done by opening a different folder that includes the folder you're working in. So say we have `/project` and `/project/src` and `/project/build`, you're probably interested in having `src` open in two instances of VSCode, which you can achieve by opening `/project` and `/project/src`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to accepted answer, here's the trick if you want to open same project in two different windows but showing two different git branches:

Copy the project folder and open that folder!

If you want two windows in two different git branches then this simple trick works. I don't know of any other solutions.

Comment: This works but is not ideal because you now have to maintain two repos. Instead use `git worktree`, which is intended specifically for this. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works, but I don't really like the fact that the folder is opened into an unnamed workspace, and upon closing window, we will be prompted to save that workspace. I am expecting more like Sublime Text like behavior.

Luckily there is VSCodium, VSCode's twin/clone without telemetry to Microsoft. So I ended up opening the folder once in either VSCode or VSCodium, then a second time in the other. This so far worked quite well for me.

Comment: This behavior is so idiotic. Like I need a keyboard shortcut to be able open up another workspace, then quickly create a new one for the same project quickly when I close it?!

Answer (score 2):

In VSCode 1.84.2, simply `File > Duplicate Workspace` in `Menu Bar`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this for working in two branches side by side and then I realized it was not possible because you cannot have two active branches in exact same git repo folder.

So, if you are looking to do the same, you should instead just make a copy of a folder and switch to another branch there. Options described in other answers will not work for this scenario due to fundamental way git works.

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, I figured out how to do this via the CLI

```bash
# open the first window
code <folder>

# force open a new window
code -n

# tell vscode to attach the target folder to the last active window
code -a <folder>
```

---

alternatively, if you do this a ton, you can just create a .code-workspace file for the duplicated workspace, and then simply

```bash
code <folder>
code <folder-dupl>.code-workspace
```

Creating the workspace is simple, just open the folder in vscode, open the command palette (`F1`), and search for "Workspaces: Duplicate as Workspace in New Window"

Then in the new window, simply open the command palette and search for "Workspaces: Save Workspace As..."

The benefit of this, is that the duplicated workspace is now "named", and will not ask to save the new workspace configuration *every* time you close it

Answer (score 0):

If you want a window to display on all virtual desktops

Method: 1

1. win + tab then right click on vs code.
2. List item select *show this window on all desktops* option.

you can see vs code in all virtual desktops

Method: 2
Simply duplicate the workspace

1. crtl + shift + p
2. search 'duplicate as workspace in new window'

↘️
[see image ️️️](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE2YK.png)
[see image ️️️](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2oC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2oC.png)

Comment: use your words in addition to images (so that this answer is understandable even without the image).