# How to open folder in new vs code instance by right clicking on the folder in the existing vs code instance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have open two folders inside a VS Code instance.

For example *(folder name)*: A and B

I want to open the folder B in a new instance of VS Code, but there is no option to open by right-clicking on the folder.

[image]

Even Atom has the option to open the folder in a new instance.

[image]

Comment: Related post - [Open the same directory twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49707703/465053)

Answer (score 34):

This extension allows you to open a folder in a new vscode window.
[Open Folder Context Menus for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrisdias.vscode-opennewinstance)

Comment: If all else fails, hope there's an extension to solve the gap/problem. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Bless your sharing heart.

Answer (score 24):

You can go via File > New window or ctrl+shift+n for a new window, and open the second folder there.

Or the "window.openFoldersInNewWindow" setting:

```
// Controls if folders should open in a new window or replace the last active window.
// - default: folders will open in a new window unless a folder is picked from within the application (e.g. via the File menu)
// - on: folders will open in a new window
// - off: folders will replace the last active window
// Note that there can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the -new-window or -reuse-window command line option).
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "default",
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the question I have asked.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I found the option by pressing `cmd+,` and searching for `open folders in new window`. I set it to `on` and it now works fine.

Comment: for files use: openFileInNewWindow

Answer (score 11):

Create a registry File e.g. OpenOnRightClick.reg

Add these lines to the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Change the location of visual studio code as per your installation directory
Now just double click on the OpenOnRightClick.reg file, confirm if asked !
All done ! on you right click you will have a open with Code option.

Answer (score 10):

Let's make it very simple

1. In vscode , Go to Files --> New Window, as shown in the image below. This will open a blank vscode window, where we will open new project.

[image]

2. Drag the project folder and drop it into the vscode. as shown in the below image

[image]

That's it. New blank window has the new project opened.

**Another way is discussed below**

1. Go to Folder URL which you want to open in the `vscode`. On the file location, type in the URL  `cmd`
2. cmd prompt will open with the folder URL.
3. In the cmd prompt, type `code .`
4. Your folder will open in the new `vscode` window.

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted that feature in my editor so I saved my settings and preferences and then I reinstalled VS Code in order to check the box that adds "Open with Code" as action in the context menu:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiOcl.png)

Comment: easiest solution. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way it is asked in the question, but doing the same things in another way.

In windows, there is a simple way to open the folder in visual studio.

If you are in any folder just type cmd on top and press enter key, It will open the command prompt.

[image]

Then type `code .` and press enter. It will open the visual studio code with the current folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a x64 bit install of VS Code you can use this. This will give you new right click options in the Windows Explorer to open the folder as a project when right clicking in a folder and when right clicking a file as seen here:
[image: VSCode Open Folder Context Menu]

> And right clicking a file

[image: open]
Save the .reg script something like `openFolderAndFilesInVSCodeWithRightClickMenu.reg` and add it to your registry.

```html
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```