# Reopen duplicated workspace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-workspace

You can duplicate the current workspace through multiple means, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345426/7264739) (**File** -> **Duplicate workspace**). Then you can work on some other set of files there.

Then, if you close/reopen with proper settings, you get both workspaces back. However, if you accidentally open something else first, e.g. some app runs it as `EDITOR`, the workspaces are not reopened and only the non-duplicated one stays on the recent workspace list.

Is there any way to recover the duplicated workspace after such incident? If so, how?

Comment: does it work for you to just save each one as a separate workspace file? (with a ".code-workspace" extension) I don't think it would help with reopening, but I think it would help with getting VS Code to remember workspace state for each one separately.

Comment: Not quite. I'd prefer for it to be automatic. And also to recover the duplicated workspace I lost, if possible, although this part is not too important.